# Adding two params of a predicate that aren't static

Tags: math, prolog, arithmetic-expressions

I'm trying to add two numbers together

```
add(num1, num2, output) :-
    output is num1 + num2.
```

Let's say X is 1 and Y is 3, but they're not static, just variables.
    `add(X, Y, out)`.

I get a `error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)` error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is a case-sensitive language and a variable name has to be character sequence made by letters, digits and underscore characters and **has to begin with an uppercase letter or underscore character**.

Therefore, 
`add(Num1, Num2, Output) :- 
        Output is Num1 + Num2.` 
would work.